# How to Query more than one lakh records through salesforce data loader

Tags: soql, data-loader

I Have some huge excel files with lakhs of data in each file.And all those files have email columns.Based on the email columns i need to query the records in salesforce. I separated email column and constructed a where clause using the email.But dataloader hits the SOQL governor limits 20000 is the soql character limit .What will be the possible ways to do these mass exports other than splitting the data?

Comment: It might be more effective to pull out all the data using dataloader to csv and using Excel or another tool outside Salesforce to do the comparison as that would avoid the SOQL limits.

Comment: One more item - please use standard English to describe the size of your record set - lakhs and crores are only used in the Indian subcontinent and this is a multinational site.

Comment: @DaveHumm thanks for your response .We have tried this and i guess there is no other way to do this.